# Tab Host Activity Example not working in Android

Tags: android, selector, android-tabhost

I have put together a very simple Tab Host demo in Android for learning purposes. It's documented here: http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/04/android-tabactivity-tab-layout-demo-tab.html

I followed the steps as indicated but it's not working. Please help me. My code is:

**TabhostActivity.java**

```
  package com.example.tabhostdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TabHost;


public class TabHostActivity extends TabActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_host);
         Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
         TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
         TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
         Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab

         // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
         intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HomeActivity.class);
         spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("home")
         .setIndicator("HOME", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.home1))
         .setContent(intent);
         tabHost.addTab(spec);

         // Do the same for the other tabs

         intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AboutActivity.class);
         spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("about")
         .setIndicator("ABOUT", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.about1))
         .setContent(intent);
         tabHost.addTab(spec);


         intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ContactActivity.class);
         spec = tabHost
         .newTabSpec("contact")
         .setIndicator("CONTACT",
         res.getDrawable(R.drawable.contact1))
         .setContent(intent);
         tabHost.addTab(spec);

         //set tab which one you want open first time 0 or 1 or 2
         tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);


         }

         }
```

**/Drawable/home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/home1"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/home2" />
</selector>
```

**/Drawable/contact.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/contact1"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/contact2" />
</selector>
```

**/Drawable/about.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/about1"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/about2" />
</selector>
```

Comment: tabhost is depricated please try to use FragmentTabHost like http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html

Comment: `TabHost` is not deprecated. How *its not working*?

Comment: `TabActivity`
 is depricated.

Comment: ok...so any another way..

Comment: i did the same example everythig seems great, try the same example maybe you miss something.

Comment: i dont know..y my app stop runnig..!

Comment: @Basbous-hey...this is not runnig for me..!

Comment: @Basbous-I can succesfully run it now..but the problem is now..m not getting images of "home","contact",and "about"..lease review my updaed code...thanx in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tab activity been deprecated.Switch over to Fragments.

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-navigation-tabs-containing-listview-to-action-bar-in-android/

Comment: @Ramji-i can run my program now but not getting images from, drawable...!